# Accordion back to default - javascript only

Tags: javascript, accordion

I'm trying to code an accordion but when trying to get it to its default look (no paragraph showing on the second click of the same list item) nothing happens even though I have it as toggle

For some reason toggle isn't really working and there's always one of the paragraphs showing. How can I have them all back to "hidden" after exploring the accordion?

Thanks

```js
  var list = document.querySelector("ul");
   var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("li");

   for(var i=0; i<listItems.length; i++){
    listItems[i].addEventListener("click", show);        }

   
   function show(){
    var p = document.querySelectorAll("p");
    var num = this.dataset.num;
      
    for(var j=0; j<p.length; j++){
                      p[j].classList.add("hidden");   
                  }

    p[num].classList.toggle("hidden");   
    }
```

```css
  ul {list-style: none;
   margin-left:30px;
   width:300px;
   height:300px;}

  li{ border:1px solid red;
  width:298px;
  height:80px;
  background-color: grey; }

  p{ width:299px;
   height:80px;
   background-color: lightgrey;}

  .hidden{ display:none; }
```

```html
 <ul>
  <li data-num="0">Home
   <p class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. </p>
  </li>
  <li data-num="1">Career
   <p class="hidden">Aenean sed ipsum libero. Praesent nisl id viverra.</p>
  </li>
  <li data-num="2">Contacts
   <p class="hidden">Nullam tristique ex eu libero sodales posuere.</p>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have clicked on and showing a paragraph, and then click it again,
then inside the for loop you are hiding all the paragraphs so the visible paragraph will be hide but in the next line after the for loop you are toggling the hidden, so it will showing up again.

Show function should be like this

```
    function show() {
        var p = document.querySelectorAll("p");
        var num = this.dataset.num;

        for (var j = 0; j < p.length; j++) {
            if (j != num) {//Check this if
                p[j].classList.add("hidden");
            }
        }

        p[num].classList.toggle("hidden");
     }
```

inside the for loop we hide all the paragraphs except clicked one, and then after the for loop we toggle the class of clicked paragraph (So if it's hidden then show up, if it's showing then it will hide).

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3yjmcs18/)